# how to hide a button programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have to create a button programmatically, and set an image background at that button. There is one condition, I want to hide that button and show a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`, but I don't know how.

The button is still visible and the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` falls on it.

Here is my code:

```
if (filemodels.fileType == @"project" && filemodels.fileExpanse == @"none") {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    NSLog(@"open expanse");
    //[displayBut isHidden];
    //displayBut.hidden = YES;
    //[displayBut setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    displayBut.alpha = 0.0;

}
```

Can anyone help?

**Update:**

Regarding [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244929/how-to-hide-a-button-programmatically/4244988#4244988)'s answer. I have changed it as per his suggestion, but the button is still not hiding.

The code is like this:

```
if ([filemodels.fileType isEqualToString:@"project"] && [filemodels.fileExpanse isEqualToString:@"none"]) {

     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:nil];
     [displayBut setHidden:YES];
     [displayBut setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: please use comments or update your question if you need to elicit or provide more information. Don't use answers for this purpose. thanks.

Comment: i would also set the button to be disabled (`displayBut.enabled=FALSE` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merged update/question as answer into OP]

Answer (score 2):

The 1st problem with your code is if-condition - you compare not the string values, but pointer values and so don't get right result. The correct way to compare strings in your case is to use `-isEqualToString:` method:

```
if ([filemodels.fileType isEqualToString:@"project"] && [filemodels.fileExpanse isEqualToString:@"none"]){
...
```

Then if you previously set your cell's accessoryView to be a displayBtn then you may need to set it to nil to make cell use accessoryType instead of your custom view - just making it hidden may be insufficient here.